# R retrieve only the value of a variable

Tags: r, variables

This may be a super dumb question, that I feel like I should know the answer to.

I am using a package called maxstat, when I run a test I get output such as the following:

```
Maximally selected Wilcoxon statistics using none

data:  x and scores 
M = 8.3107, p-value = NA
sample estimates:
estimated cutpoint 
            0.6421
```

I call this output "x" and I only want to retrieve the value of the estimated cutpoint.  So I try:

```
> x$estimate
estimated cutpoint 
        0.6421
```

How do I just get the value 0.6421 without the attached name "estimated cutpoint"?

I want to put this value in a table and when I use cbind or rbind to attach the value(s) the name gets attached as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See `?unname`, e.g.

```
unname(x$estimate)
```

Although all this does is drop the `"names"` attribute. If you have several of these to un-name, it might be easier to bind them all together and then get rid of the row or column names en masse via one of:

```
rownames(obj) <- NULL
colnames(obj) <- NULL
```

Or

```
dimnames(obj) <- list(NULL, NULL)
```

where `obj` is the object containing the data you wish to un-name.